# Javascript loop with dynamic jquery val() not being picked up

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to pick out the value of an input box using jquery.
No probs there

```
$('#id_of_my_input_box_1').val();
```

But I need several so decided to put them into a loop:

============

```
var config_total_instances = '==some value='

for (var x = 1; x <= config_total_instances; x++) {

    if (isset($('#id_of_my_input_box_'+x).val())) {

        alert($('#id_of_my_input_box_'+x).val());

    }

}
```

============

If I submit the form and I've got say 10 input boxes, the code above doesn't alert a value if the relevant input box has value.
I'm using a function below to check for values.

============

```
function isset(my_variable) {

    if (my_variable == null || my_variable == '' || my_variable == undefined)

        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

============

Am I missing something vital..? :-(

Addition: I shoudl add that I'm askign why I don't get the value of 
$('#id_of_my_input_box_'+x).val()
echoed out in my alert box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending @Faber75's answer. You can set a class name for all your text element and then use something like this

```
$("input:text.clsname").each(function(){
    if (isset(this.value)) {
        alert(this.value);
    }
});
```

In your current code if you are assigning a string to `config_total_instances` then it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

don't consider my message an answer, more of a tip.
For a simplier code you could consider adding a class to the textboxes you need to check.
For example adding to all the inputs you need to check the class="sample" you could the use the jquery selector $(".sample") , returning you all the items and then you could simply do
$(".sample").length to count the items and $(".sample")[0].val() (or similar) to get/test values.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? (note that there are three =)

```
if (my_variable === null || my_variable == '' || my_variable === undefined)
```

As an alternative to this try

```
if (typeof(my_variable) == 'null' || my_variable == '' || typeof(my_variable) == 'undefined')
```

Comment: Will do..
but even without the if statement, the value of a dymnamic element is still not echoed.

Comment: Have you put your code into a jQuery(document).ready()? If not, it is normal that you won't echo anything since the object does not exist at the time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but can't you just get all the `<input>`'s in a `<form>` that aren't `:empty` if that's the end goal of what you're trying to accomplish?

```
$('form#some_id input:not(:empty)').each(function () {
     // do something with $(this).val() now that you have
     // all the non-empty <input> boxes?
});
```

Or if you're just trying to tell if the user left some `<input>` blank, something like:

```
$('form#some_id').submit(function (e) {
     if ($(this).find('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked), input[type="text"][value=""], select:not(:selected), textarea:empty').length > 0) {
         e.preventDefault(); // stops the form from posting, do whatever else you want
     }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/form-selectors/

Comment: The ID's need to be dynamic $('#my_input_name_1') (2, 3, 4 etc)
There's many other form elements that can quite happily be empty, but the dynamic ones are kinda treated separatly.
My question relates to a larger jquery function I'm writing, so I do just need to know why the above code doesn't echo a value.

Comment: <input> is empty by definition because it's a single tag. :empty only works on tags that need to be closed (e.g. <form> ... </form>).

Comment: Beertastic: what do each need their own ID? Mike: yes, you're right - fixed